# Differential equation. $ \sqrt{3+y^2}dx-x\cdot dy=x^2\cdot dy $ Check my steps

Tags: differential

I have equation $ \sqrt{3+y^2}dx-x\cdot dy=x^2\cdot dy $ and I need to solve it with separation method.

My try:

$-x^2\cdot dy-x\cdot dy=-\sqrt{3+y^2}\cdot dx$

$-x(x+1)\cdot dy=-\sqrt{3+y^2}\cdot dx $

$\frac{-x(x+1)}{dx}=-\frac{\sqrt{3+y^2}}{dy}$

And another step should be integrals for both sides. Are my steps correct or not?

Comment: How did $x\cdot dx$ become $x\cdot dy$ in the first step?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy mistake, it should be dy, changed it

Comment: Invert the fractions and integarte.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy like this? $\int \frac{dx}{-x(x+1)}$ and $-\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{3+y^2}}$

Comment: In fact you don't have a minus sign on LHS, other thant that, yes.

Comment: @zwim thanks, noticed that

Comment: Your steps are correct and you no need of minus signs on both sides, you can cancel them and reciprocal on both sides. After integrate it which gives you the result.

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite the equation as
$$
\dfrac{1}{x+x^2} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3+y^2}}dy.
$$

By integration, you get
$$
\log \frac{|x|}{|1+x|} = \textrm{arcsinh} y + C 
$$

So, the solution can be given in an explicit form:

$$
y = \sinh\left(\log \dfrac{|x|}{|x+1|}-C\right).
$$